# Logic behind searching string using substring

Tags: scala, substring

My question is pretty straightforward...  Can someone explain to me the logic behind searching string x using substring y and then returning the index of x where y is found within x?

I am taking a CS course that covers multiple languages and this seems to be a recurring question on assignments, but I do not understand how this works.  Currently we are working on Scala and are to create a function that accepts 2 parameters and then we are supposed to do what I mentioned above.

If someone could explain how you search a string for the contents of another string I would really appreciate it.  Even extra thanks for an example.

All from scratch, no using libraries :/

Comment: What have you tried? You'll learn more about it by trying it yourself, not just asking for an answer here.

Comment: Substring searching is a very well-known topic with many algorithms. It should be easy to find an introductory algorithm book which covers it, probably describing naive and advanced algorithms. I personally like Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms, but there are many others. The only thing you have to do is to understand the algorithm and program it in Scala. You may even find a wikipedia article about substring searching, or other descriptions with google.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the real life implementations are much more clever than this, but the simplest way of getting this done would be something like this (non Scala specific):

1. Start looping on your first Strings characters with an index variable, lets call it `i`
2. At each loop, check if we still have more or as much characters left in the first String, as the length of the second String. If not, return early with `-1`
3. Now start another (nested loop) and check, if the first String has matching characters from the index `i` with the second String. Always iterate on the second String from the beginning.
4. As soon as you find the first non matching character, you can break this nested loop.
5. If this nested loop iterated successfully on the first String from the index `i` and on the second String from its beginning (index 0), and all the characters matched, you can return the index `i`

Update the question if you get stuck, but if someone implements this for you, you'll learn nothing.